# chrome extension update issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to update an outdated chrome extension (I'm not a coder, just playing around to learn). It needed to be updated from the manifest 1 version to manifest 2.

After I made the update chrome required, the extension no longer works.. It goes to the options page, and then the buttons won't bring up the secondary page as it did before. I'm assuming there are more updates I need to make to the code, but don't know what?

What else do I need to change? I don't understand why it won't work if I haven't changed the html or js files, just the manifest?

my manifest:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "WatchAds",
    "version": "2.2",
    "description": "Ad Watcher.",
    "icons": {
        "48": "adaware.png",
        "128": "adaware.png"
    },

    "background": {
        "page": "main.html",
        "persistent": true
    },
    "options_page": "main.html",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "history"
    ]
}
```

main.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    #putHere {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
        span {
            color: #ddd;
                -webkit-transition: 1s;
        }
            span:hover {
                color: #000;
            }

        #putHere a, strong {
            margin-left: 20px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        img {
            margin-right: 7px;
            position: relative;
            top: 3px;
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
        }
</style>
<ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:m.displayData()">Show</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:( m.clearData() || m.displayData())">Clear</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="putHere"></ul>[/code]
```

main.js:

```
m = {
    key: 'history', 
    ls: window.localStorage,
    clearData: function() {
        m.ls.removeItem( m.key );
        m.ls.setItem( m.key, "[]" );
    },

    get: function() {
        if ( m.ls.getItem( m.key ) == null ) { 
            m.ls.setItem( m.key, "[]" );
        }

        return JSON.parse( m.ls.getItem( m.key ) );
    },

    set: function( v ) {
        m.ls.setItem( 
            m.key, 
            JSON.stringify( (m.get()).concat( [v] ) )
        );
    },

    callbackTabs: function( id, i, tab ) {
        if ( tab.status == 'complete' ) {
            m.set( { 
                date: m.date(),
                favIcon: tab.favIconUrl || '',
                url: tab.url || '',
                title: tab.title || '',
                incognito: tab.incognito
            } );
        }
    },

    date: function() {
        d = new Date();
        return '' + (
            ( d.getDate() > 9 ? d.getDate() : '0' + d.getDate() ) + ' ' + 
    ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August',
                'September','October','November','December'][d.getMonth()] +
        ' ' + d.getFullYear() + ', ' + 
            ( d.getHours() > 9 ? d.getHours() : '0' + d.getHours() ) + ':' + 
            ( d.getMinutes() > 9 ? d.getMinutes() : '0' + d.getMinutes() ) + ':' +
            ( d.getSeconds() > 9 ? d.getSeconds() : '0' + d.getSeconds() )
        );
    },

    $: function( id ) {
        return document.getElementById( id );
    },

    parseURL: function( url ) {
        var a =  document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;

        return { 
            source: url,
            protocol: a.protocol.replace(':',''),
            host: a.hostname,
            port: a.port,
            query: a.search,
            params: (function(){
                var ret = {},
                    seg = a.search.replace(/^\?/,'').split('&'),
                    len = seg.length, i = 0, s;
                for (;i<len;i++) {
                    if (!seg[i]) { continue; }
                    s = seg[i].split('=');
                    ret[s[0]] = s[1];
                }
                return ret;
            })(),
            file: (a.pathname.match(/\/([^\/?#]+)$/i) || [,''])[1],
            hash: a.hash.replace('#',''), */
            path: a.pathname.replace(/^([^\/])/,'/$1')/* ,
            relative: (a.href.match(/tp:\/\/[^\/]+(.+)/) || [,''])[1],
            segments: a.pathname.replace(/^\//,'').split('/') */
        };
    },

    displayData: function() {
        var html = '';

        (m.get()).forEach( function( v ) {
            p = m.parseURL( v.url );

            html += '<li><span>' + v.date + '</span> ' + ( v.incognito ? '<strong>incognito mode</strong> ' : '') 
            + '<a href="' + v.url + '"><img src="' 
                + ( v.favIcon ? v.favIcon : ('http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=' + p.host) ) + '"/>' 
            + ( v.title ? v.title : ((p.host + p.path ).substr( 0, 80 )) ) + '</a></li>';
        });

        m.$( 'putHere' ).innerHTML = html;

        return false;
    }
};

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( m.callbackTabs )

}
```

Comment: You could try making a minimal code to demonstrate the problem http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .  Often times that leads you to a solution, and if not, it makes the question clearer.

Comment: What do you mean make a minimal code?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve The idea is to present the minimal amount of code that is self contained that reproduces your problem.  That way other developers can help.  Often, creating that example will lead you to a solution, in which case, it would be great if you can post the solution here for the benefit of others.